# Is there a way to access private methods and variables from Eclipse's Display View?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, runtime

Is there a setting to enable access to methods with `private/protected` access modifiers and variables from Eclipse's Display View? Since you can access them from inside a Detail `Formatter` it would seem Eclipse does have access to them at run-time?

Note I have been unable to recreate this in a simple example case. I will update when I can clearly recreate the problem.

Comment: Can you please add some simple example dictating your question? I think, they are accessible be default.

Comment: Display view is intended for quick expression evaluation, if you want to traverse object tree, use Variables view or Expressions view

Comment: When there is really no way to access them, you may want to create your own version of the package.

Comment: @YogendraSingh, I created a simple test case and your right its working in that case. So now I need to figure out about what is different in my case where its not working. Perhaps it simply user error and I misunderstanding the stack context. I will report back. Thanks for your time!